# OpenScap Debian 10 Benchmarks

Tags: openscap, debian-10

The lastest openscap package I downloaded for Debian 10 does not include a datastream or benchmark for Debian 10. The latest release they have is debian 8 and I get "Not Applicable" when using this for the scan.
Can someone tell me how I can get the benchmark for debian 10? it would be called something like "ssg-debian10-xccdf.xml"

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since the Debian 10 product is present in Upstream project[1], seems the Debian package is not updated. Debian packagers should update the respective package for the distro.

[1] https://github.com/ComplianceAsCode/content